# Does rank standard function calculate rank for all records before applying filter?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know what rank function does in spark/sql.

Suppose I have 10 million records in my dataframe and there is a requirement of ranking a column and selecting only record of rank=3. Does spark still calculate the rank of all 10 million records and then select record of rank=3?

If this is how it works internally, isn't a slower process by spark?

Comment: As far as I know, first rank function will be completed and then the filter condition of rank=3 will be applied. Can you provide an example of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a example with only using 3 records:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', 3), ('a', 2), ('a', 1)
    ],
    schema=['col1', 'col2']
)

data.printSchema()
data.show(3, False)
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|a   |3   |
|a   |2   |
|a   |1   |
+----+----+
```

We rank the records by `col2` in descending order, then filter `rank=3`:

```
data2 = data.withColumn(
    'rank', func.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy(func.desc('col2')))
).filter(
    func.col('rank')==3
)

data2.show(3, False)
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|rank|
+----+----+----+
|a   |1   |3   |
+----+----+----+
```

If we use `.explain()` to check the result, here is the physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Filter (rank#15 = 3)
   +- Window [rank(col2#1L) windowspecdefinition(col1#0, col2#1L DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS rank#15], [col1#0], [col2#1L DESC NULLS LAST]
      +- Sort [col1#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, col2#1L DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col1#0, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#95]
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[col1#0,col2#1L]
```

As you see from the execution plan, the filtering operation is executed ONLY after the ranking operation, which means it will calculate the rank of all 10 million records first in your case.

When we check the DAG of your SQL execution plan, you can see that there is dependency relationship between stages and stages. In each stages records will be splitted multiple tasks to perform parallel computing. Therefore, in your case, filtering only will be executed after the ranking.

Comment: As I have 10 million records, they would be splitted among several partitions. Will it involve shuffling of data to sort and rank the records?

Comment: @VineethReddy The data must be shuffled into the same partition before sorting and ranking, unless the data is pre-sorted already. For example, you pre-sort the data and save in parquet format. When you read the data again, the parquet file contain the metadata of your file such that it will know the min and max value of particular column. In such case, metadata know the stats of your column and shuffling could be prevent.